# How to extract floating point numbers from strings surrounded by multiple characters?

Tags: python, regex, floating-point, extract

I need to know how to extract the floating point number which is within the square bracket and apostrophe.

This my  data.state

```
   state: {
      "command_args" : {
        "position" : 94.9838180542
      },
      "error_flags" : 0
      "op_mode" : 4
    }
```

I just want to extract the number 94.9838180542 and this is what I wrote:

```
   182               splitData = (data.state.split("}")[0])
   183               splitdata = ( re.findall("\d+\.\d+",splitData)  ) #Floating Point Number 
   184               print(splitdata)
```

My output is:

```
['94.9838180542']
```

Required Output:

```
94.9838180542
```

How can I remove the '[]' and the apostrophe and just extract the entire floating point number from this?

Thank you

Comment: Parse it as a JSON first since this appears to be a valid JSON.

Comment: this look a lot like a malformed json string. I would recommend you start by fixing the format, and the use a json parsing library to get the values you need.

Comment: var num = state.command_args.position will return that value when treated as JSON

Comment: (but if you want a quick answer based on the code you already have, `print(float(splitdata[0]))` will do)

Comment: Also, if your format is indeed some sort of invalid json, beware that floats came in different flavors in json: they can be negatives, and they can have exponents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re.findall returns a list of strings

```
if len(splitdata) > 0:
    num = float(splitdata[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

To strictly respond to the question posed, I will give you the code on how to fix it.

```
print(float(splitdata[0]))
```

**However**, this code will not work if there is more than one float, so that is why I would recommend:

```
print([float(item) for item in splitdata])
```

The second code bit will not remove the [], but if there are multiple floats inside the text, it convert all of them to floats properly.

Finally note: you really should make sure that your inputted json is correct and use the built in json functions in Python:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: It worked. Thanks! But  I do not understand how splitdata[0] is giving just the number? What format is ['92.38']? Is it considered as a list. How does splitdata[0] retrieve that number? Can you please explain?

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so your re.findall outputs an array, I use [0] to access the first element.  Then, I use float () to turn that first element into a float value.  Hey, could you do me a favor and upvote & mark as answer, it'd help a lot.